# Creating inline rollover images in css with 3 images

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

I am a beginner in CSS & HTML and I am trying to create 3 circle rollover images that are inline. I originally had the images inline using `display: inline-block` and that worked well had had the 3 images all in one line.

However, when I have added the code to make the images all rollover onto text this has now drastically changed the positioning. I believe the images are now sitting behind each other and the one picture that can be seen is now over-lapping onto other elements on the page.

Please see my code below. Also please excuse my code if it is all over the place (I welcome the correction) as the different codes used for this particular section in the site I have found from numerous online sources as I am still learning.

```css
.middleimgs {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  border-radius: 160px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.middleimgs:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrap">
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Invest In Your Future</h2>
  <p style="text-align: center;">
    Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews.
  </p>
  <div class="middleimgs">

    <div class="container1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="pound sign linked" width="300px" height="300px" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Targeting vertical integration with a goal to maximise share of voice.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="investing money" width="300px" height="300px" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="community" width="300px" height="300px" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Leverage blue-sky thinking while remembering to be transparent.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for the long-winded question, hoping someone can help. I am also learning Javascript so if you think it would be better done in JS please let me know too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You were super close! Looks like just a couple of changes needed to be made. First, your :hover should use the .container1 element instead of the .middleimgs element. (Like this:) `.container1:hover .overlay`. That way hovering won't activate all three text boxes at once.

To keep the containers from being stacked on top of each other you can change the `.container1{position: absolute}` to `.container1{position: relative}`

To get the three images to appear horizontally next to each other give them `display: inline-block`.

```css
.middleimgs {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  border-radius: 160px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.container1:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrap">
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Invest In Your Future</h2>
  <p style="text-align: center;">
    Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews.
  </p>
  <div class="middleimgs">

    <div class="container1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="pound sign linked" width="300px" height="300px" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Targeting vertical integration with a goal to maximise share of voice.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="investing money" width="300px" height="300px" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="community" width="300px" height="300px" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Leverage blue-sky thinking while remembering to be transparent.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew! That worked @Andrew Hulterstrom